# Who is the Jerusalem above?

Tags: galatians

Galatians 4: 25-26 NASB

> “Now this Hagar is Mount Sinai in Arabia and corresponds to the present Jerusalem, for she is in slavery with her children. But the Jerusalem above is free; she is our mother.”
> ‭‭

Who is the Jerusalem above? Within the context of this passage, it seems that in parallel to Hagar it would be Sarah, contrasting the flesh and the promise, but where does the “above” piece come in?

Answer (score 1):

Ellicott explains this "Jerusalem above" quite well:

> **(26) Jerusalem which is above**.—The ideal or heavenly Jerusalem. (Comp. Hebrews 12:22, “Ye are come to . . . the heavenly Jerusalem;”
> Revelation 21:2, “the holy city, new Jerusalem.” This “new” or
> “heavenly” Jerusalem is the seat or centre of the glorified Messianic
> kingdom, just as the old Jerusalem had been the centre of the earthly
> theocracy. The conception of the “heavenly Jerusalem” among the Jews,
> like the rest of their Messianic beliefs, took a materialistic form.
> It was to be a real but gorgeous city suspended in mid-air, “three
> parasangs” (11¼ miles) above the earthly city. Sometimes it is
> regarded as the exact copy of its earthly counterpart, and at other
> times as forming a perfect square. (Comp. Revelation 21:16.) No such
> materialistic notions attach to the idea as presented by St. Paul.
> “Jerusalem which is above” is to him a spiritual city, of which the
> Christian is a member here and now. It is part of the Messianic
> kingdom, to the whole of which the Apostle gave an ideal character. He
> could not but do so, seeing that the kingdom began with the coming of
> its King, though there was no earthly and visible realisation of it.
> The Christian “conversation” (or, rather, commonwealth, the
> constitution that he was under) was “in heaven,” while he himself was
> upon earth. (See Philippians 3:20.)

Matthew Poole is similar:

> **which is above**, or from above, which answereth to Sarah, and is said to be above, because revealed from heaven by Christ, sent out of
> the bosom of the Father, not as the law was revealed upon earth, upon
> Mount Sinai. Hence apostates from the doctrine of the gospel, are said
> to turn from him who speaketh from heaven, Hebrews 12:25. Or else it
> is said to be above, because it is the assembly of the firstborn
> written in heaven, Galatians 4:23: hence the gospel church is called
> the heavenly Jerusalem, Galatians 4:22. Of this gospel church the
> apostle saith, that it is free; i.e. free from the yoke and bondage of
> the ceremonial law, or from the covenant and curse of the law.